# How to add new item in an array with value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've an array with some values and I want to add a new element to this array.

I have an array like this:

```
arr1 = [
 {'id': '1', 'data': 'data1'},
 {'id': '2', 'data': 'data2'}
]

val = ['value1','value2']
```

and I want to add `val` array in `arr1` and make a new array like this:

```
arr1 = [
 {'id': '1', 'data': 'data1', 'val': 'value1'},
 {'id': '2', 'data': 'data2', 'val': 'value2'}
]
```

How can I do that ?
I'm new to `Javascript`, so any type of help can be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr1 = [{
    'id': '1',
    'data': 'data1'
  },
  {
    'id': '2',
    'data': 'data2'
  }
]

const val = ['value1', 'value2']

const res = arr1.map((el, index) => ({ ...el,
  val: val[index]
}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over either array via a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) or [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Use the loop variable to access the elements of both arrays and create the new property by assigning to it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  arr1[i].val = val[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr1.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.val = val[index]
})
```

This will iterate over each item in the array and add the new property to each, referencing the indices in the `val` array to get the proper value.

Homework: [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)